# Mix of c#, c++ and C

Tags: c#, c++, c, visual-studio-2008, wrapper

I've a mix of `C#` and `C++` code and `main()` being in `C#`.

Now I need to use third party `C` code in my `C++` to debug a problem. I added a couple of `C` files into my `C++` project in Visual Studio and  I used one of the functions in `C` file using `extern C` declaration in `C++`. The function in `C` file has few Windows development APIs like `GetEnvironmentVariable()`, `FindFirstFile()` etc and they do not seem to be working.

They always fail. Also when `Abort()` is called in `C` function, the execution control does not seem to be returned to the `C++`. `C++` code is hung. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Yes. You're missing telling us exactly how they fail and exactly what the problem is. Details are critical. "they do not seem to be working. They always fail" gives very little hints about anything.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at **[SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)** as it will interpret your **C++/C** code and create a **C#** wrapper for it.

Answer (score 0):

Win32 API stuff works the same in C++ and C so if they're failing it must be a bug in the third-party C code.

Comment: Thank you. My analysis seems to be going that way. Nothing concrete yet.